# Check if a set of genes fall more on a specific cluster than other clusters

Tags: networks, clustering

I have a network which I clustered into 11 smaller clusters. I have a set of genes and I would like to check if statistically significant number of these genes fall on any specific cluster. One method which I thought of was to find which percentage of a total cluster were made up of my genes of interest. For example, say 60% of the genes in a cluster were the genes in my list. However, I was hoping that there was a better way to do this. [This study on honey bees](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4755009/) has done something of the kind.

I would appreciate if there was a way to do something similar. I do not know how to replicate what they have done in the study. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have problem with the hypergeometric test or with the later methods they do?

Comment: @Llopis I have never done hypergenometric tests before and I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

A hypergeometric test is related to the fisher test, in a table with one  dimension being some factors and the other one some other factors it is tested if they are independent. In R you con do this:

```
data <- matrix(c(0, 1, 2, 5), ncol = 2, nro = 2)
fisher.test(data)
```

Or you can use the specific function [`phyper`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8382806/2886003), to see the relation between them you can read this [question and answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/82688/105234)